# Regex that allow void fractional part of number

Tags: c#, regex

`@"[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?"`   -this is a regex I have wrote for numbers
 it allows 
 [+-] minus before the number
 digits before and digits after the point

the question is
 how to change this to allow "not finished" values
 so that input of "5." - is fine too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the dot outside of the captruing group and then make it as optional.

```
@"[+-]?\d+\.?\d*"
```

Use anchors if necessary.

```
@"^[+-]?\d+\.?\d*$"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
@"[+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?"
```

If you want to allow `+` or `-` or `-.` or `+.` etc also then:

```
@"[+-]?\d*(\.\d*)?"
```